# How to copy or read Spool file in C# (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to copy or read spool file. but when i try to read/copy it. i get following error.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\00007.SPL' is denied.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String
>   destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)    at
>   WDISYS.wfPrintServerLogin.Addedtest(Object sender, PrintJobEventArgs
>   e) in
>   F:\Projects\Asp.Net\AT\A2Test\WDISYS\WDISYS\wfPrintServerLogin.cs:line
>   255

my code is like below :

```
try
{
    string dest = @"C:\Windows\sfwitch\spls";

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\Windows\sfwitch\spls"))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Windows\sfwitch\spls");
    }

    string spl_file = (e.PrintJob.JobId).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
    string printSpoolPath = @"C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS";
    printSpoolPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(printSpoolPath, spl_file) + ".SPL";

    System.IO.File.Copy(printSpoolPath, System.IO.Path.Combine(dest, spl_file) + ".SPL");
}
catch (Exception ex80)
{

    LogHelper.WriteErrorLog("Spool file create problem", ex80);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as Administrator ?

Comment: It is happening in client pc. it works in my development pc.

Comment: Then the user doesn't have access to that location. Your client needs to try to run the application as administrator.

Comment: client has ran the program as administrator. still this is happening. what's why i have asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the spool folder full rights. Right-click the folder, click "Properties", and then click the "Security" tab. Click "Edit" after "Advanced" and select Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries shown here that apply to child objects.